# How can I make canvas element act as a background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to use the canvas element as the background for my page.

How can I make "We craft brand experiences for companies and nonprofits making a difference." show up on top of the background?

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Confetti Party</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
        <h1>we craft brand experiences for companies and nonprofits making a difference. </h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, my `h1` tag is not on top of  **background.**

Comment: Put it above the canvas if you dont want it below it

Comment: I made some formatting edits to the question, but I left the text as is because I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  Are you trying to reposition this text within the rendered HTML page? (And if so, where do you want it exactly?)    What do you mean by "on top of the style, not individually anywhere"?

Comment: @DanielBeck Thankyou very much for formatting edits . i am really sorry for my english, i have also edited the question myself a bit . please look into it again .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you effectively want to make the canvas your page's background. This is rather trivial can be done by taking advantage of the CSS `z-index` property:

```js
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//  configurables
///////////////////////////////////////////////
// background color
// var bg = [159, 240, 167]
var bg = [255, 255, 225]

// maximum number of particles present at any time
var num_particles = 150

// chace of split
var chance_birth = 0.37

// chance of termination/death
var chance_death = 0.38

var cols = ['#FF5722', '#FF9800', '#FF9800', '#FF9800', '#FF9800', '#B71C1C', '#00BCD4', '#00BCD4', '#009688']

///////////////////////////////////////////////
//  the other stuff
///////////////////////////////////////////////
//var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
//document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(canvas)
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var particles = []
var step = 0
var step_max = 360
setup()
window.addEventListener("resize", setup)

function setup() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight
  fill(1)
}

function fill(amt) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  ctx.fillStyle = `rgba(${bg[0]}, ${bg[1]}, ${bg[2]}, ${amt})`
  ctx.fill()
}

setInterval(animate, 1000/60)
// window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function animate() {
  fill(0.01)
  step = (step + 1) % step_max
  draw()
  // window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){animate()})
}

function getRandCol () {
  return cols[Math.floor(Math.random() * cols.length)]
}

function draw() {
  var pad = 0.02
  var p
  if (particles.length < num_particles && step % 2 === 0) {
    var x = (Math.random() * (1 - pad * 2) + pad) * canvas.width
    var y = canvas.height + Math.random()*10 //(Math.random() * (1 - pad * 2) + pad) * canvas.height
    p = new Particle(x, y, ctx)
    particles.push(p)
  }

  var i

  for (i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
    particles[i].update()
    particles[i].draw()

    // branch-birth
    if (step % 4 === 0 && Math.random() < chance_birth && particles.length < num_particles) {
      var x = particles[i].x
      var y = particles[i].y
      p = new Particle(x, y, ctx)
      p.color = particles[i].color
      particles.push(p)
    }
  }


  // death
  for (i = particles.length -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    p = particles[i]
    if ((step % 4 === 0 && Math.random() < chance_death) || p.y < -20 || p.x < -20 || p.x > canvas.width + 20) {
      particles.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }

  // draw links
  var dist_max = 60
  for (i = particles.length -1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
    p = particles[i]

  }



}

function Particle (x, y, ctx) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.px = x
  this.py = y
  this.dx_min = -20
  this.dx_max = 20
  this.dy_min = -1
  this.dy_max = -25
  this.s = 0.8
  this.ctx = ctx
  this.color = getRandCol() //"#ee9977"

  this.update = function () {
    this.px = this.px * this.s + this.x * (1 - this.s)
    this.py = this.py * this.s + this.y * (1 - this.s)
    var dxy = this.dxy()
    this.x = this.s * this.x + (Math.random() * dxy.dx + this.x) * (1 - this.s)
    this.y = this.s * this.y + (Math.random() * dxy.dy + this.y) * (1 - this.s)
  }

  this.draw = function () {
    // var v = Math.min(this.vsq(), 500)
    ctx.lineWidth = 2 //Math.sqrt(v)/3
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(this.px, this.py)
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color
    ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y)
    ctx.lineCap = "round"
    ctx.stroke()
  }

  this.dxy = function () {
    var dx = (this.dx_max - this.dx_min) * Math.random() + this.dx_min
    var dy = (this.dy_max - this.dy_min) * Math.random() + this.dy_min
    return {dx, dy}
  }

  this.vsq = function () {
    var x = this.px - this.x
    var y = this.py - this.y
    return x * x + y * y
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{
  /* Move the canvas to a low z-index (background) */
  z-index: -1;
}
.wrapup{
  /* This class creates a div that is positioned on top of everything outside of it */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:100;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin:0;
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
}
body {
  /* Just some stuff to clean up the look by filling page and removing scrollbars */
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden; 
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Confetti Party</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
        <div class="wrapup">
          <h1>we craft brand experiences for companies and nonprofits making a difference. </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

As for how you decide to position the h1 on the page, that is up to you, but anything you place inside of the `wrapup` div will appear atop the canvas.

Comment: All is good, but isn't it worthy to add a `position:relative;` to the `canvas` element css (just in case)? Any difference between adding and not?

Answer (score -2):

Change `<h1>` to

```
<h1 style="position:fixed; top:500px; left:300px;">
```

You can adjust the 500px and 300px values to move it to a different position on the screen. You can also use a combination of % and margin to automatically center the element, for example:

```
top:50%; margin-top:-6em;
```

If you want the text to scroll down with the page, use position:absolute instead.

Comment: Folks, if you downvote, also give a reason please? I'm pretty sure my answer is what the OP was asking about!

Comment: I imagine they downvoted because this isn't responsive, and is kind of a hack.